# Recieve Bitcoin value notifications on iPhone

Tags: exchanges, value, alert-system

I would like every day at a set time to receive a notification on my iPhone with the current Bitcoin value in Euros. How can I have this?

Comment: Do you want an app that uses push notification? Or an e-mail that is sent to you? Or a text message (SMS) sent?

Comment: Either an app that uses push notification or a text message

Comment: it is possible to make one using a cronjob and php if you know anything about it. If not let me know and i'll write one and put it up as a free service (text messaging fees apply, and will have ads on the text message).

Comment: Which market are you interested in? Bitcoin value can vary up to 10% between exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Numerous](http://numerousapp.com) has a "Bitcoin Value" number. You can enable notifications for it.

Comment: This app is really amazing and fits my needs perfectly. Thank you for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

The [Bitcoin Ticker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bitcoin-ticker/id440229059?mt=8) app seems like it would fit your needs nicely.

Comment: I can only find an "Alert me when 1BTC is more/less than x euro's". Also useful, but is there also an option that sends push notifications daily regardless of what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

com. BOY i have gone a head and made a free service for anyone. This service runs on my freicoin block explorer. you will get updates on the last btc/usd, btc/euro price as well as the last BTC/FRC price.

http://1.cr.rs
In the upper right hand corner is a link that says

"Click here to get daily BTC/FRC price updates sent to your phone"
(link: http://1.cr.rs/sms/)

click that link, and insert your phone number.... note you must have a usa based cellphone at this time (I only did this quickly so you could have information).

Texts you twice a day at 800 EDT and 2000EDT.

enjoy! 
If you (anyone reading this) are out of the usa, give me the name of your carrier and the email address extension your provider gives for sms messages and I will add your carrier to the list.

Comment: I live in the Netherlands (You could have seen that on my profile ;) and using Vodafone. Where can I find the e-mail address extension?

Comment: hah yeah i could have... i am looking for it now... google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but you can get notifications from

[www.bitcoinreminder.com](http://www.bitcoinreminder.com)

depending on price changes or specific limits